Clear active sheet without clearing formulas or Letters
I have written this script to clear data and keep formulas, however I would like to keep
the letters. IE column titles I have made so that when I enter data I know where it goes.
This is my current script:
  function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Utills')
   .addItem("Entire current sheet", 'entireSheet')
   .addItem('Current active range', 'activeRange')
   .addToUi();
  }

  function entireSheet() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    const range = sheet.getDataRange();
    keepFormulas(range);
  }

   function activeRange() {
     const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
     const range = sheet.getActiveRange();
     keepFormulas(range);
   }

   function keepFormulas(range) {
     const formulas = range.getFormulas();
     range.clearContent();
     range.setFormulas(formulas);
   }

I am completely stumped  on how to achieve this.

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

Exclude Header row from clearing
To exclude the header row from being cleared, you should specify a custom range using various methods from Apps Script's Class Range like getLastRow, getLastColumn etc. This modification achieves the goal of clearing the text while preserving the formulas and the header row.
Code
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Utills')
    .addItem("Entire current sheet", 'entireSheet')
    .addItem('Current active range', 'activeRange')
    .addToUi();
}

function entireSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const lastcolumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, lastcolumn);
  keepFormulas(range);
}

function activeRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  
  const startRow = range.getRow();
  const startCol = range.getColumn();
  const numRows = range.getNumRows();
  const numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  
  const newRange = (startRow === 1) ? 
    sheet.getRange(2, startCol, numRows - 1, numCols) : 
    range;
    
  keepFormulas(newRange);
}

function keepFormulas(range) {
  const formulas = range.getFormulas();
  range.clearContent();
  range.setFormulas(formulas);
}

Sample Outout
Before running the script

After running the script

References:
Class Range Methods

@marc Ostrensky please edit your post and try to provide your expected output so we can understand your situation better.

You can target a range that excludes row 1. This means the range you'd pass to the keepFormulas function would be from row 2 and onwards. This will preserve row 1 and let you keep your titles
const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
const lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

// Adjust the range to start at row 2 and include all columns
const rangeWithoutHeaderRow = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, lastColumn); 
// Start at 2nd Row, 1st Column
sheet.setActiveSelection(range);


In the sheet there is multiple title blocks ie when you put data in one area it transfers to other areas to complete different calculations. How would i got about specifying multiple cells to save titles. I am trying to make the sheet as user friendly as possible.

You'd need to exclude those rows (and/or columns) for the range above. The code for that would be less than ideal, an easy way would be to have that row/column hard-coded such that it is excluded from the range. Essentially you'd do something like clearing two ranges. The first range was discussed above until the hardcoded row/column. Then the second range would be after that hardcoded row/column to the end. You'd repeat for additional rows/columns that need to be preserved. It's less than ideal though, maybe it makes sense to split this into two sheets to not have to splice the range.
